# How to enable auto-loading of several next photos in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing

I'm using Lightroom 4.1 to review, cherry pick and postprocess a bunch of Canon RAW photos from a big shooting session. I use the Library view in Loupe mode to review the photos and pick up the best ones. When I finish staring at one photo and optionally press <kbd>B</kbd> to add it to the quick collection for later processing, I press the <kbd>→</kbd> button to go to the next photo.

The problem is that the process of switching to the next photo is quite slow. My photos are located on a home server on the other end of a Gigabit ethernet cable, so the data transfer itself should be fast. So I suppose that most (CPU) time is spent doing something with the photo, like resizing to fit the screen, applying WB, etc.

Anyway, is it possible to tell Lightroom to preload photos in advance to speed up each switch to the next photo? So that I may leave it open for several minutes, and it would process, say, first 50 photos starting from the currently selected one.

Comment: In fact, I see that Lightroom loads one next photo in advance. But never more.

Comment: Note, 1:1 previews and pre-loading photos for screen viewing are totally different things. This bug of not pre-loading photos is still there as of version 5.4, June 12, 2014. Lightroom shows "Loading..." 90% of the time for me, despite having current 1:1 previews built for the entire folder. This is not due to hardware either, because it is equally true on the super fast Flash storage within my Mac Pro (late 2013). On other software I can cherry pick 1000 photos in 5 minutes. Lightroom simply refuses to preload the next images in the filmstrip, which slows down the same workflow to 30 minutes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way to do this is to have Lightroom **Render 1:1 previews** for you. You can have it do this at import or you can force it later by selecting multiple photos in the Grid view of the Library module and choose Library > Previews > Render 1:1 Previews.

More information on optimizing Lightrooms performance can be found [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/optimize-performance-lightroom.html).

See Also:

- [How can I force Lightroom to render previews for my collection?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13850/how-can-i-force-lightroom-to-render-previews-for-my-collection)
- [Does anyone have any tips to make Lightroom run faster?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/694/does-anyone-have-any-tips-to-make-lightroom-run-faster)